# How can I access the aiohttp's Request from a RestRequest in minos

Tags: python, microservices, aiohttp, minos

I have a handling function decorated with the `@enroute.rest.command` decorator, so that my function receives a `RestRequest` instance, but I want to directly access the `aiohttp.web.Request` to directly access to the `rel_url` attribute. How can I do that?

My current code looks like:

```py
from minos.networks import RestRequest, RestResponse, enroute


@enroute.rest.command("/products/create", "POST")
async def handle_product_create(request: RestRequest) -> RestResponse:
    ...
    return RestResponse("created!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `minos.networks.RestRequest` provides the `raw_request` attribute, which gives access to the inner `aiohttp.web.Request` instance, so that you can access any of its methods or attributes

```py
from aiohttp import web
from minos.networks import RestRequest, RestResponse, enroute


@enroute.rest.command("/products/create", "POST")
async def handle_product_create(request: RestRequest) -> RestResponse:
    raw_request: web.Request = request.raw_request
    print(raw_request.rel_url)
    ...
    return RestResponse("created!)
```